# Can I apply dark Briwax over boiled linseed oil?

Tags: boiled-linseed-oil, wax

I've made some shelving out of scaffold boards and I was initially planning on a light, natural finish. After one application of boiled linseed oil (BLO) I changed my mind and now I want to go dark. It's been about 10 days since I applied the BLO.

I've got some Briwax (Jacobean colour) here so I'm hoping I can just start applying this over the BLO.

Is this a bad idea? Will the BLO alter the finish? If so should I sand the wood in an attempt to remove the BLO? Or should I accept my mistake and stick with the light finish?

Comment: I'm almost positive this or a similar question has been asked before. Have you checked the previous Q&A?

Comment: I've searched for "boiled linseed oil" and clicked through 4 pages of results but couldn't find any mention of applying wax over it. Plausible that I've missed it though

Comment: I'm positive that there is advice in there about wax over oil, and that putting wax over "drying" oils like boiled linseed is not only fine, it is one of the oldest finishing traditions. Maybe like this one: https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/q/8058/5572

Comment: Like @jdv, this rings a bell and there may be an existing Q&A that covers the territory. But in general you have no concerns here, you can go for it. Briwax is used by someone somewhere over *everything*. And 10 days at current temps is likely more than enough for the BLO to be well along the path to curing even with more than one coat applied.

Comment: @Graphus define "current temps". Yesterday it was mid-80s (F), today it's 68° F. It was very humid yesterday and it's been pouring today, humidity matters, too. :)

Comment: @FreeMan, warmer weather.